# Correct use of an If statement in echo?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a variable called `$position` which has a value selected from a database.
I am having an issue displaying the `$position` value in my dropdown menu as the selected value on page load.
The `$position` variable does echo out the correct value outside of this code.

I read about the Ternary Operator method so I have used that here instead of normal IF statment but it still does not work. Is my code correct? Is there another method I should use?

Thanks

My Code

```
$number = $_GET['id'];
$number = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$number);

$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT s_code, s_type, s_position, s_idno, s_firstnames, s_email, s_cellno FROM smco WHERE s_ainumber = ?") or die(mysqli_error());

$stmt->bind_param('s', $number);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($code, $type, $position, $idno, $name, $email, $cell);

$stmt->fetch();

$stmt->close();

echo "<td width=\"62%\" align=\"left\">
<p><b>Position:</b></p>
<select name=\"position\">
<option value=\"AQ\" (($position == 'AQ') ? \"selected='selected'\")>Account Queries</option>
<option value=\"KM\" (($position == 'KM') ? \"selected='selected'\")>Key Account Manager</option>
<option value=\"MD\" (($position == 'MD') ? \"selected='selected'\")>Managing Director</option>
<option value=\"RB\" (($position == 'RB') ? \"selected='selected'\")>Rebates</option>
<option value=\"BY\" (($position == 'BY') ? \"selected='selected'\")>Store Buyer</option>
<option value=\"OW\" (($position == 'OW') ? \"selected='selected'\")>Store Owner</option>
</select>
</td>";
```

Comment: @swapnesh - I didnt show it here as it displays correctly elsewhere but I have added it above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '<option value="">' . (true ? 'true' : 'false') . '</option>';
```

In you case:

```
echo "<option value=\"AQ\"" . (($position == 'AQ') ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . ">Account Queries</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to concat strings like that :

```
echo "foo is " . ($foo == true ? "true" : "false") . " whatever echo";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm getting your question right but you can simplify this.

Just write a function like this:

```
function is_postion($value, $position){

    if($value == $position) echo 'selected="selected"';

    return;


}
```

Then simply put it inside the HTML rather that using echo for the whole thing. So:

```
<option value="AQ" <?php is_position('AQ', $position); ?> >Account Queries</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to wrap all the HTML into the echo. It's enough to use PHP for dynamic parts only.
Second, you placed PHP code inside the string. So, it didn't worked.
Third, when using *(expr) ? :* (ternary operator) you missed the false branch.

Try using this.

```
   <td width="62%" align="left">
        <p><b>Position:</b></p>
        <select name="position">
        <option value="AQ"<?=$position == 'AQ' ? "selected='selected'" : ""?>>Account Queries</option>
        <option value="KM"<?=$position == 'KM' ? "selected='selected'" : ""?>>Key Account Manager</option>
        <option value="MD"<?=$position == 'MD' ? "selected='selected'" : ""?>>Managing Director</option>
        <option value="RB"<?=$position == 'RB' ? "selected='selected'" : ""?>>Rebates</option>
        <option value="BY"<?=$position == 'BY' ? "selected='selected'" : ""?>>Store Buyer</option>
        <option value="OW"<?=$position == 'OW' ? "selected='selected'" : ""?>>Store Owner</option>
        </select>
</td>
```

Comment: I wrapped the HTML in an echo as the code was part of an if statement which I didn't show sorry about that.

Comment: Up to you. I prefer to move the PHP out, because the code is more readable and PHP don't need to waste resources on large string processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td width='62%' align='left'>
    <p><b>Position:</b></p>

    <select name='position'>
        <option value='AQ' <?php echo $position == 'AQ' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Account Queries</option>
        <option value='KM' <?php echo $position == 'KM' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Key Account Manager</option>
        <option value='MD' <?php echo $position == 'MD' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Managing Director</option>
        <option value='RB' <?php echo $position == 'RB' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Rebates</option>
        <option value='BY' <?php echo $position == 'BY' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Store Buyer</option>
        <option value='OW' <?php echo $position == 'OW' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Store Owner</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
    echo "<td width=\"62%\" align=\"left\">
<p><b>Position:</b></p>
<select name=\"position\">
<option value=\"AQ\"  ".(($position == "AQ") ? "Selected=selected" : "")." >Account Queries</option>
<option value=\"KM\" ".(($position == "KM") ? "Selected='selected'" : "")." >Key Account Manager</option>
<option value=\"MD\" ".(($position == "MD") ? "Selected='selected'" : "")." >Managing Director</option>
<option value=\"RB\" ".(($position == "RB") ? "Selected='selected'" : "")." >Rebates</option>
<option value=\"BY\" ".(($position == "BY") ? "Selected='selected'" : "")." >Store Buyer</option>
<option value=\"OW\" ".(($position == "OW") ? "Selected='selected'" : "").">Store Owner</option>
</select>
</td>";
```